Buildroot with Graphical Acceleration on RPi5
Summary: Need to find what is missing/not yet developed that is preventing Buildroot OS from achieving graphical acceleration in a Buildroot system for the RPi5.
I've been able to get a buildroot OS booting on an RPI5 using 2023.11.3 base, applying the following patches: [Buildroot] [PATCH v2 1/2] arch: add support 16k page size on ARM64
I want to get graphical acceleration working similarly to how it's supported by the RPI4 by default in buildroot if you enable mesa3d->Gallium v3d driver. Here's what I've tried so far:
jrk@wan-hq-wks-173:~/src/buildroot-pi$ git diff
diff --git a/board/raspberrypi/config_5.txt b/board/raspberrypi/config_5.txt
index 1372222e08..3e696808ca 100644
--- a/board/raspberrypi/config_5.txt
+++ b/board/raspberrypi/config_5.txt
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@ display_auto_detect=1
 auto_initramfs=1

 # Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
-dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
+dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d-pi5
 max_framebuffers=2

 # Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
diff --git a/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.hash b/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.hash
index 0f4ca05831..93d1665063 100644
--- a/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.hash
+++ b/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.hash
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # From https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/23.2/docs/relnotes/23.2.1.rst
 sha256  64de0616fc2d801f929ab1ac2a4f16b3e2783c4309a724c8a259b20df8bbc1cc  mesa-23.2.1.tar.xz
+sha256  cd3d6c60121dea73abbae99d399dc2facaecde1a8c6bd647e6d85410ff4b577b  mesa-23.3.6.tar.xz
 # License
 sha256  a00275a53178e2645fb65be99a785c110513446a5071ff2c698ed260ad917d75  docs/license.rst
diff --git a/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.mk b/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.mk
index 4b360c8a8f..ec8fc9ba12 100644
--- a/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.mk
+++ b/package/mesa3d/mesa3d.mk
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 ################################################################################

 # When updating the version, please also update mesa3d-headers
-MESA3D_VERSION = 23.2.1
+MESA3D_VERSION = 23.3.6
 MESA3D_SOURCE = mesa-$(MESA3D_VERSION).tar.xz
 MESA3D_SITE = https://archive.mesa3d.org
 MESA3D_LICENSE = MIT, SGI, Khronos

The Mesa version upgrade was a bit of just taking the need to upgrade Mesa on faith from this Phoronix article. But on boot, unlike in Raspbian, there is no graphical v3d module loaded with lsmod. There are no modules loaded. Any ideas what could be missing? Something missing in kernel config? Kernel is raspberrypi's version of 6.1.
